# Git / Github - Multiple offshoot repos/themes from base repo?

Tags: git, github

Working on an Eleventy site and would like to use it as a base for future projects. I thought I could fork it on Github and then just merge future changes made to the base, but you can not fork your own repo. Or if I cloned the base repo would there be any way to get changes from the base to the child repos? Not sure what the right approach to this type of structure is, but open to all possibilities.

Also, would there be any way to automatically push/get the changes made to the base to all the offshoot themes on each update? Would save a lot of time if I didn't have to pull/fetch on each individual project.

Any advice is very much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: It seems like functionally, a branch would work fine for this. I know there is a lot of recommendations to keep branches short lived etc. but if you are the only person working on this and the only person managing merges, and your releases don't rely critically on your merges, I don't seee a problem. I'm sure you would find after some time that the branches would be impossible to merge but I don't see this as any different to a fork type solution. Iam a Git amatuer though so I'm keen to see any rebutttal on this

Comment: Great suggestion, could see why this could be one approach. 

For this scenario, it could be a bit counterintuitive. Ffor example, if someone else was to work on this project(s) in the future it could cause problems. In terms of hosting, it could be a bit overcomplicated to set up Netlify to deploy specific sites from different branchs.